# iOS Custom Templates missing methods in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, templates

I have a custom set of Xcode templates I used for app development. I had an Xcode 4 version working, then I attempted to update and install them for Xcode 5 and I noticed two important parts were missing from my code.  The @autorelease section inside of main.m and application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method in my AppDelegate.m file.

main.m
(How it should look):

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

(How mine looks):

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
}
```

AppDelegate.m
(Missing this method):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

My templates reorganize the files that build the app inside of Xcode and in the projects actual folder too, to create a 3 tier folder structure of data, programming (business), and presentation.  My question is does moving these files cause this error or is there another template I am failing to notice?  Where are these two pieces of code being added?  I have checked all the template files I can find and don't see what I need to modify to get these templates working again.

The templates I have modified are:

- Base.xctemplate
- Bundle Base.xctemplate
- Cocoa Touch Application.xctemplate
- iPhone Base.xctemplate
- Objective-C Application.xctemplate
- Single View Application.xctemplate
- Storyboard Application.xctemplate

Thanks any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the bugs I was having.  For the @autorelease, I missed adding my path to its key in the Cocoa Touch Application.xctemplate.

```
<key>programming/core/main.m:main:UIApplicationMain</key>
<string>@autoreleasepool {
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([___VARIABLE_classPrefix:identifier___AppDelegate class]));
}
</string>
```

And for the application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:  method I had the wrong path in the Storyboard Application.xctemplate.

```
    <key>programming/controllers/___VARIABLE_classPrefix:identifier___AppDelegate.m:applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Beginning</key>
        <string>- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.</string>
        <key>End</key>
        <string>    return YES;
}
        </string>
        <key>Indent</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
    </dict>
```

Sorry if I wasted anyone's time looking for the answer for these.  Go figure spend two days trying to find the bug on your own, then finally decide to ask for help, and find the bug shortly after. :/

Hope this helps someone in the future.